# Store string as hex without converting

Tags: c++, hex

I have a string value:

```
string str = "2018";
```

Now I have to store in `unsigned char` array as hex representation but not really convert to hex:

```
unsigned char    data [2];  //[0x20,0x18]
```

If I do it this way

```
data[0] = 0x20;
data[1] = 0x18;
```

It works, but my input is `string`, how I can resolve it?

## Edit

If my input is `unsigned char` instead of `string`   like

```
  unsigned char y1 = 20;
  unsigned char y2 = 18;
```

Is there any better way?.

Comment: That's [*binary-coded decimal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) and you can't do it without *some* kind of "conversion".

Comment: C or C++? Pick one.

Comment: I am using c++ in Qt

Comment: As for how to do it, first of all you need a loop to iterate over all characters in the string. Begin there. How to do the loop depends on the programming language you use and what kind of "string" the input is which also depends on the language. So please pick *one* language.

Comment: 'As hex without converting' and 'store in unsigned char array as hex representation but not really convert to hex` are both contradictions in terms. Please clarify.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Converting "2018" to 0x20 0x18 IS a straight hex conversion.

Comment: @WilliamJBagshaw The string `"2018"` is five bytes, and with ASCII encoding they are `0x32`, `0x30`, `0x31`, `0x38` and `0x00`. Converting those bytes into `0x20` and `0x18` is not quite what I would call "a straight hex conversion". Also, the OP wanted *no* conversion, and that's impossible even with "a straight hex conversion" as it's still a *conversion*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The "without conversion" is silly, a hex string to int converter does the job. Any other solution is also a "conversion". I think the author ether a) thinks the conversion is not hex string to int.(it is) b) has been tasked with writing there own string to hex convert.

Answer (score 2):

If you can assume the string to have 4 digits, you can convert it to BCD format simply and efficiently this way:

```
void convert_to_bcd4(unsigned char *data, const char *str) {
    data[0] = (str[0] - '0') * 16 + (str[1] - '0');
    data[1] = (str[2] - '0') * 16 + (str[3] - '0');
}
```

Comment: Just wondering - why you mixed `[]` and `*` notation if they both do the same ?

Comment: @FilipKočica: the `*`  in `(str[0] - '0') * 16` is the multiplication operator, not the pointer dereferencing operator. `str[0] - '0'` is the value of the digit character, between `0` and `9`, multiplying it by `16` produces a byte value among `0x00`, `0x10`, ... `0x90`. Adding the digit value of the next character produces the BCD byte value for the 2 digits, as required.

Comment: I meant function params `void convert_to_bcd4(unsigned char data[], const char *str)`

Comment: @FilipKočica This mix up is very typical for C programming. Strings are `char * str` and the nth char in the string is `str[n]`.  You were probably weened on `string`. I hope you get the idea of what the code is doing. It may need reworking a bit to be more C++ like.

Comment: @FilipKočica: sorry about that, it was indeed inconsistent. No semantic difference, but consistency is better.

Answer (score 2):

A brief research made me find this function [`QString::toInt(bool&, int)`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qstring.html#toInt) which can be useful for your intent.

Basically you could:

```
if(str.size() % 2 == 1){
    str = '0' + str;
}
for(int i = 0; i < str.size() / 2; i++){
    data[i] = (str[2*i] + str[2*i+1]).toInt(res, 16);
}
```

I did not try this code, there surely a better way to extract the substring, and probably a more efficient way than to iterate over it.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could try something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "2018";
    unsigned i;

    std::sscanf(s.c_str(), "%04x", &i);

    unsigned char data[2];
    data[0] = i >> 8;
    data[1] = i;

    std::cout << std::hex << (int)data[0] << " " << (int)data[1] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/SyYKUl

Prints:

```
20 18
```

Answer (score 1):

You can complete the conversion of "2018" to 0x20 0x18 using a hex string to binary converter. I think, for example, sscanf("%x",....) will do this. This typically gives an int. You can extract the byte values from the int in the normal way. (This method does not check for errors.)